# Do I need to escape DB input?

Tags: php, database, validation, post, pdo

I read that with PDO you don't need to escape variables if you use prepare and pass the variables in execute:

```
$st = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (name,email) VALUES (?,?)");
$st->execute(array($_POST['name'], $_POST['email']));
```

Is this tru?

Or do I still need to do something with $_POST there?

Comment: Despite not needing escaping, be sure to check the input values for sanity, acceptable ranges, properly formatted email, etc, and return error messages to your user where appropriate.

Comment: yes, I was just curious about sql attacks

Comment: As long as you're strict about what you place into your query and where you do it (i.e. use parameters at all times, never ever *ever* allow user-supplied data to leak into concatenated parts of dynamic queries) then you'll be safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On prepared statements, no escaping is necessary (and escaping things yourself will result in double-escaping, causing escaped data to be written to the DB).

However, PDO prepared statements CANNOT handle all query variants, and sometimes you'll have to insert "foreign" data directly into a query string, which means you'll be responsible for escaping it properly. In particular, dynamic queries where the table and/or field names change cannot be specified using prepared statements. e.g.

```
SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ?=?
```

cannot be done. Only values can specified with placeholders.

Comment: Exactly. fields and table names cannot be specified with placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you don't need to escape anything. Parameterized queries are *totally freakin' awesome!* :)

Long answer: No, you don't need to escape anything *as it's going into the database*. However, you should still use `htmlspecialchars` when displaying the database output from queries to prevent XSS attacks, otherwise you'll end up with someone stuffing something like this in an arbitrary field:

`<script type="text/javascript">alert('sup, I'm in ur site!');</script>`.

Comment: Stressing the *when displaying the database output*. You should in general **not** store HTML in the database unless your field truly is HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This is true; the code is correct (although you may want to handle the case that `$_POST['name']` is not set).

PDO's prepared statement functionality hands over the values in a format that does not need explicit escaping.

Comment: It's somewhat important to note that PDO doesn't actually do any escaping, it just isolates the data from query language entirely.